# Sending audio file created with RecordRTC to my server

Tags: xmlhttprequest, recordrtc

I am new to working with Javascript, PHP, and with servers generally. I am working on a web page that will record audio from the user and save it to my server, using RecordRTC. I'm a bit confused about the XMLHttpRequest portion - how do I alter the following code to send to my server instead of the webrtc server?

```
        function uploadToServer(recordRTC, callback) {
            var blob = recordRTC instanceof Blob ? recordRTC : recordRTC.blob;
            var fileType = blob.type.split('/')[0] || 'audio';
            var fileName = (Math.random() * 1000).toString().replace('.', '');

            if (fileType === 'audio') {
                fileName += '.' + (!!navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? 'ogg' : 'wav');
            } else {
                fileName += '.webm';
            }

            // create FormData
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
            formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);

            callback('Uploading ' + fileType + ' recording to server.');

            makeXMLHttpRequest('https://webrtcweb.com/RecordRTC/', formData, function(progress) {
                if (progress !== 'upload-ended') {
                    callback(progress);
                    return;
                }

                var initialURL = 'https://webrtcweb.com/RecordRTC/uploads/';

                callback('ended', initialURL + fileName);

                listOfFilesUploaded.push(initialURL + fileName);
            });
        }
```

Via my web hosting provider, I'm using an Apache server, phpMyAdmin, and a mySQL database. Do I just replace

```
    makeXMLHttpRequest(https://webrtcweb.com/RecordRTC/
```

with "https://mywebsite.com" and replace

```
    var initialURL = 'https://webrtcweb.com/RecordRTC/uploads/';
```

with the path to the file I created to hold these audio files (https://mywebsite.com/uploads)? Then set permissions for that folder to allow public write capabilities (this seems unsafe, is there a good method)?

This is the makeXMLHttpRequest function:

```
        function makeXMLHttpRequest(url, data, callback) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    callback('upload-ended');
                }
            };

            request.upload.onloadstart = function() {
                callback('Upload started...');
            };

            request.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
                callback('Upload Progress ' + Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100) + "%");
            };

            request.upload.onload = function() {
                callback('progress-about-to-end');
            };

            request.upload.onload = function() {
                callback('progress-ended');
            };

            request.upload.onerror = function(error) {
                callback('Failed to upload to server');
                console.error('XMLHttpRequest failed', error);
            };

            request.upload.onabort = function(error) {
                callback('Upload aborted.');
                console.error('XMLHttpRequest aborted', error);
            };

            request.open('POST', url);
            request.send(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please make sure that your PHP server is running top over SSL (HTTPs)
2. Create a directory and name it `uploadFiles`
3. Create a sub-directory and name it `uploads`

#### Structure of the directories:

```
https://server.com/uploadFiles           -> to upload files
https://server.com/uploadFiles/uploads   -> to store files
```

#### index.php

Now create or upload following `index.php` file on this path: `https://server.com/uploadFiles`

```
<?php
// File Name: "index.php"
// via https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/tree/master/RecordRTC-to-PHP
foreach(array('video', 'audio') as $type) {
    if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

        echo 'uploads/';

        $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
        $uploadDirectory = 'uploads/'.$fileName;

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
            echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
        }

        echo($fileName);
    }
}
?>
```

#### Why sub-directory?

Nested directory `uploads` will be used to store your uploaded files. You will get URLs similar to this:

```
https://server.com/uploadFiles/uploads/filename.webm
```

#### Longer file upload issues:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/wiki/PHP-Upload-Issues

`upload_max_filesize` MUST be `500MB` or greater.

`max_execution_time` MUST be at least `10800` (or greater).

It is recommended to modify `php.ini` otherwise create `.htaccess`.

#### How to link my own server?

Simply replace `https://webrtcweb.com/RecordRTC/` with your own URL i.e. `https://server.com/uploadFiles/`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I realized I copied the HTML and JS source code from the demo page rather than using the files on the Github repository. The index.html there does not have the webrtc link - it refers to save.php, which makes more sense to me. 

I think I completed all of these steps, but I'm not sure if it's working since it's set to auto-delete the files when the window closes. I would like to keep the files stored in the uploads folder. Should I delete the whole 'window.onbeforeunload' function that contains the link to delete.php, as well as 'delete.php' itself?

Comment: nevermind, figured out on my own that deleting the "onbeforeunload" function does work to do this. Thanks for your help!